# Git: Checkout a previous commit and work in the branch created by that commit

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-code

I'm building a website, and it builds fine locally, but doesn't on the server. The server pulls the code from Github, so I must upload previous commits to my Github to see which commit the server fails on.

I tried

```
git checkout 1111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Which put me in a detached head state, and when I tried to commit I got

```
HEAD detached at 1111111
Revert currently in progress.
  (run "git revert --continue" to continue)
  (use "git revert --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

So I checkedout master to get out of the detached head and then tried

```
git checkout -b 1111111111111111111111111111111111
```

and got

```
Switched to a new branch 1111111111111111111111111111111111
```

But when I build my website, it still builds the version on master
So I try

```
git switch 1111111111111111111111111111111111
```

And get

```
warning: refname '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111' is ambiguous.
Git normally never creates a ref that ends with 40 hex characters
because it will be ignored when you just specify 40-hex. These refs
may be created by mistake. For example,

  git switch -c $br $(git rev-parse ...)

where "$br" is somehow empty and a 40-hex ref is created. Please
examine these refs and maybe delete them. Turn this message off by
running "git config advice.objectNameWarning false"
fatal: cannot switch branch while reverting
Consider "git revert --quit" or "git worktree add".
```

So I try this with no problems

```
git config advice.objectNameWarning false
```

And then I try

```
git switch 1111111111111111111111111111111111
warning: refname '1111111111111111111111111111111111' is ambiguous.
fatal: cannot switch branch while reverting
Consider "git revert --quit" or "git worktree add".
```

And I think I'm still working in the master branch, visual studio code still says I'm in the master branch at the bottom

[image]

I don't even see my branch available

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why did you checkout a branch whilst reverting a commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you ran `git checkout -b` with an object ID, you created a new branch that was named the same thing as an object ID, since the first argument after `-b` is the name of the branch.  Creating branches named like that is not a good idea, as Git's telling you.

First, delete the branch you created by using `git branch -d` (or `git branch -D`) and passing it the 40-character hex name you passed to `git checkout -b`.

Once you've done that, the best way to create a new named branch from a revision is to run `git checkout -b NEW-BRANCH-NAME REVISION`.  Note that the revision comes *after* the new branch name.  You can then push that branch to the server to test it out and have it built there.  If you want to reuse the same branch for your next test, use `git checkout -B` instead of `git checkout -b`, which will overwrite the branch, and then force push the branch to the server.

It may be that your build process only works against `master`, in which case you'd have to force-push over that branch.  Hopefully if that's the case, you'll fix your build process so that it builds from a branch first, which is the better option.